# Three.js render function and trackballcontrols

Tags: three.js

I'm using `THREE.CSS3DRenderer` and `THREE.TrackballControls` which calls render on change. I'd like to change the HTML elements (approximately 200) when the camera moves but if I do it on each render call, the number of calculations would be really high.

Ideally I'd like to discard small movements (not visible to the human eye) and only apply my calculations when needed. 
E.g if `camera.x = 0.015529912611241384` and then its moved, I only run my function if the difference between the old and new position is 0.0001

Any ideas on how to accomplish that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calling the function that changes the html function directly, raise a flag called `change_html_elements`.
Have another function that is running every `x` milliseconds, call the function that updates the html elements and resets the flag to false.